# Notification bar appears all white in light mode

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-10-mobile, template10

I'm using Template 10 and in Windows 10 Mobile when I choose the light mode, the notifications bar appears all white

[image: http://imgur.com/F6T7TKy.png]

and can not see the notifications, the hours, etc.

In the dark mode everything seems fine image:

[image: http://imgur.com/j7nXoee.png]

How do I solve this?

Comment: right because you didn't sent the background color of the status bar.  it's not handled automagically. The framework doesn't take that into account don't think it ever will.  Left up to developer since it could be a contrasting color or close in hue to the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this in my hamburger's override for `UIElement CreateRootElement()` after my database setup/migrations are done.

```
 if(Template10.Utils.DeviceUtils.Current().IsPhone()){
   var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
   if(statusBar != null)
   {  
       if(Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Light)
          //background && foreground or combination, and dependent on color choices
          statusBar.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;
      else if(Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark
          statusBar.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
  }
}
```

Template10 already has a lot of the logic built in just have to know where it is.  As @Jay Zuo said you have to also include the Mobile reference as well..

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved the problem.
I only have one question, for example: if the application theme is dark and I change to the light theme, it only updates the status bar if I close and open the app. Is there any way to update the status bar when I change the application theme?

Comment: There is some code smell snippets that exist but it requires altering the base T10 code a little to facilitate that change.  Unfortunately the current GitHub repository isn't in shape right now to be forking and attempting a change as the library is currently going thru a code refactoring.

Comment: Thank you! Another question, this is possible? When the theme is light: 
`statusBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
statusBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;`

Comment: you can set it that way but does it make sense?

Comment: I want in the light theme of the app, the background of the status bar to be black and the icons white, as it happens when the theme of the application is in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

As @mvermef said, to solve this problem, we can set the color used in status bar according to application's theme. We can get application's theme by using [Application.RequestedTheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_RequestedTheme) property and set status bar's color by using properties in [Status​Bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.statusbar) Class. For a simple example:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;

    if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
    {
        var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
        if (statusBar != null)
        {
            if (Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Light)
            {
                statusBar.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;
            }
            else if (Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark)
            {
                statusBar.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note to use `Status​Bar` Class, we need reference **Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP** in the project.

Comment: I put my code in the file: App.xaml.cs in public override async Task OnStartAsync (StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args). In your example you have this code in MainPage. Is there a difference?

Comment: @FernandoSousa I put in in MainPage just for example. Using it in `OnStartAsync` should also work.